# How should a watchdog timer be used?

Tags: microcontroller, reset, watchdog

I've seen and written programs in which the internal watchdog just resets in a super loop and trigers only when something goes wrong and forces the whole system to crash.

I've also seen it can be used as a "system reset" when the program intentionally goes into an infinite loop and waits for the watchdog timer to expire triggering a reset.

But, apart from reseting it over and over again in a super loop, is there any more effective way to make use of that peripheral in case you need something robust?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a general answer for this -- I would make a software watchdog that resets the processor if it recognizes that things get bad, and that is in turn responsible for resetting the hardware watchdog.  But there's infinite ways to do that.  Don't put it in a periodic ISR that'll keep running while the rest of the application is in flames -- I've actually seen that, in code reviews.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part. What do you mean by "a periodic ISR"? Regarding your first point, if the code is developed to catch unexpected scenarios you can just perform a "software reset" if the system includes any. Or you can just pause "infinite loop" until the watchdog triggers a reset.

Comment: ISR = "interrupt service routine"

Comment: On my first point (actually, both) -- if you write the code so that it can be gravely misbehaving (i.e., "in flames") and the watchdog is still getting reset, then what's the point?

Comment: @TimWescott Yes I know the abbreviation. I didn't understand why it is bad to have an ISR that runs periodically.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a periodic ISR.  Having an ISR that resets the watchdog when everything else in the application has failed completely defeats the point of a watchdog -- it would be better to *not even use* a watchdog in that case.

Comment: @TimWescott I didn't mean ISR when I said super loop.

Comment: @TimWescott that's a valid concern about watchdog servicing in an ISR, but it still can be done (and useful) **if** that same ISR also implements a secondary software watchdog, and that secondary watchdog gets serviced in the main loop. That way you have the classic "main loop protection" of a watchdog, but also a guard against the corner case where interrupts get disabled and never get re-enabled. Two watchdogs are better than one.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub That's what I thought at the beginning but I wasn't sure. I've done that second "software" watchdog and I can confirm that it's much more reliable than the internal watchdog. Actually I could just not use the internal watchdog at all and rely on the software one.

Comment: @MrBit I believe the hardware watchdog is vital and must be used. In my experience the #1 value of a hardware watchdog is resetting the processor if it has gone into an unexpected infinite loop or if the program counter has become corrupted. In either of those cases a software watchdog cannot help you.

Comment: uC need a watchdog in case of hung IO routines or unexpected external transients or/ehm ... bad code.   RTOS code also need real-time overrun monitors that can cause sync issues or Real-time timeout issues.

Comment: https://betterembsw.blogspot.com/search/label/watchdog%20timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watchdog timer is used to reset you system if it gets stuck in an infinite loop or waiting for external devices to respond.

You configure the watchdog timer for an appropriate timeout depending on the system. (few milliseconds to several seconds)

In you program you need to reset the watchdog once in a while to prevent it from running out and trigger a system reset.

The trick is to reset the watchdog often enough, and not inside loops that might get stuck. 
If you put the watchdog reset inside a timer interrupt routine to prevent i from running out there is no point in having it enabled in the first place.